# how to search for a specific from and to keyword in a file and print the sentence in python

Tags: python, regex, file, search

I am trying to get a file as an input and search for a special character.
I am giving from and to keys as input.
if the to keyword is in the next line i should print till the to keyword is found.

```
for line in contents:

if line.startswith("*CHI: ") :

       line = line.strip("*")
       tokenize = line.split()
       p.token_filter(tokenize)
```

say i have a file:

```
       *CHI: (hi) new [/] friend [//] there [/-] [ bch] [ bch ] /[]/ [/=]
<new>
<there>.
%mod: hi there.
*CHI: <dude>
<there>
*CHI: &=sighs <and instead the> [//] and then the gira?e got it and gave it to the elephant . 
*CHI: <he> [/] <he> [/] he hold it .
*CHI: then [/-] the doctor give the [/] money to the man
*CHI: and (i)s then (.) the little (.) gira?e is crying because it (i)s sinking
```

By using the above code i am getting the output as follows:

```
['new', '[/]', 'friend', '[//]', 'there', 'bch', '/[]/']
['dude', 'dude']
['and', 'and', 'instead', 'the', 'the', '[//]', 'and', 'then', 'the', 'gira?e', 'got', 'it', 'and', 'gave', 'it', 'to', 'the', 'elephant', '.']
['he', 'he', '[/]', 'he', 'he', '[/]', 'he', 'hold', 'it', '.']
['then', 'the', 'doctor', 'give', 'the', '[/]', 'money', 'to', 'the', 'man']
['and', 'then', '(.)', 'the', 'little', '(.)', 'gira?e', 'is', 'crying', 'because', 'it', 'sinking']
```

My another aim is i should print 
['new', '[/]', 'friend', '[//]', 'there', 'bch', '/[]/' **'new' 'there' '.'** ]

Comment: "but i am not able to print "new" and "there"" ....Well those lines don't start with `*` so your first if statement returns `False`

Comment: Do you want to print every line? Not sure what the goal is

Comment: @SuperStew OP might be looking to grab everything between two `*`s.

Comment: Are you after something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/QgEXyB/1) ?

Comment: the regex answer is probably the best way to go

Comment: @Mathwog What is your desired output?

Comment: @Mathwog sure there is, but why not make it easy?

Comment: Can someone reply to the edited question. Sorry for the ambiguity in the question

Answer (score 1):

for arbitrary text you can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "*foo* bar *foobar*"
>>> re.findall("\*[^/*]*\*", text)
['*foo*', '*foobar*']
```

To get rid of the asterisks:

```
>>> [s.replace("*", "") for s in re.findall("\*[^/*]*\*", text)]
['foo', 'foobar']
```

Comment: Or just wrap the `[^/*]*` in a capturing group? No need to escape the `*` in a character set by the way. Your slash is the wrong way round too.

Comment: can someone explain me ("\*[^/*]*\*", text) this part alone

Answer (score 1):

If you can read the file and convert it into a string.
We can use

```
string = "123123STRINGabcabc"

def find_between( string, first, last ):
    try:
        start = string.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = string.index( last, start )
        return string[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

print find_between( string, "123", "abc" )
```

gives

```
123STRING
```